# Unable to write new entries in DB

Tags: java, php, android, sql, database

I am trying to post some data to database. The code seems to be fine but it is not creating new entries in database. What mistake am I making?

PhP script:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','abcd','12345');
mysql_connect_db('xmytestdb');

$hello = $_POST['hello'];

$world = $_POST['world'];

$query = "INSERT INTO 'myTable' VALUES ('','".mysql_real_escape_string($hello)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($world)."')";

mysql_query($query);

?>
```

Regards

Comment: Should 'myTable' be in quoted like that?

Comment: i tried it without quotes as well. still unable to create new enteries

Comment: provide columns in myTable.Check the count in values. if anyone misses provide column names

Answer (score 1):

Insert `$hello` and `$world` into which column?

Assuming columns as hello and world..

`$query = "INSERT INTO myTable (hello, world) VALUES ('mysql_real_escape_string($hello)','mysql_real_escape_string($world)')";`

Comment: Define "insert into" without columns is possible in MySQL but I think it is a problem with the column definition too.

Comment: Maybe because of wrong syntax in `$post`, it should be equal to `$_POST['world']`. The bracket.

Comment: I don't know java..but does `$_POST` parameter properly sent?

Comment: how can I check that? I don't know php .

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['hello'])) { echo "exist"; } else { echo "does not exist"; }` replace hello with world to check that too..

Comment: where would echo print. I mean I am executing this script from my code

Comment: Add that script to the form action file, or in the file where the parameters are posted..

Answer (score 0):

$query = "INSERT INTO myTable SET hello='".mysql_real_escape_string($hello)."' , world='".mysql_real_escape_string($world)."'";

try query like this. :) i hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use procedures or functions to insert data into the database. Your website is vulnerable to SQL injection . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

replce code

```
 mysql_connect('localhost','abcd','12345');
 mysql_connect_db('xmytestdb');
```

with

```
 $con =  mysql_connect('localhost','abcd','12345');
 mysql_select_db('xmytestdb',$con);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to match the input data with field names

INSERT INTO table1 (fieldname1, fieldname2) VALUES (data1, data2)